# Having trouble with Ropsten faucet using geth

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I'm new to Ethereum and I'm still learning the ropes and I figured I'd deploy different smart contracts on Ropsten to test whether they perform as intended. The trouble is different faucets limit how much rETH they distribute to one IP, so I figured I'd use [RopstenSink](https://github.com/xiaoyao1991/RopstenSink) to get slightly more than I could get normally. Everything went smoothly up till when you have to run the sink using the code

```
sink <address> <numEthers> <httpProvider, if you run geth locally, then it should be http://localhost:8545>
```

I tried with the following code and different variations of it (obviously address is longer) to no avail. After using it, an error code pops up:

```
sink <0x123....789> <10> <http://localhost:8545>
(anonymous): Line 1:51 Unexpected token <
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm guessing it has something to do with the actual amount.

Comment: You probably aren't supposed to put the `<` and `>` signs in.

Comment: Yeah, it was one of the first things that came to mind. Still [throws out an error](https://preview.ibb.co/fXUJJ9/geth2.jpg).

Comment: It looks like maybe you're trying to run `sink` inside a geth console? I assume it's meant to be run directly from the command line.

Comment: Ah yeah, sorry about that. [This](https://serving.photos.photobox.com/790371764eeb3ef51a03f1b90632640281b4cef9d0806a14eb9bebdf373c522730c890a8.jpg) is the uncropped version. Since I'm new to this, I might have done something wrong beforehand that I haven't noticed.

Comment: The problem appears to be exactly what you said. You're trying to run the command inside a geth console, but it needs to be run directly from the command line.

Comment: How would I go about running it from the command line? The directory has no files I know of that could run the command and just directly running the command would give me a "not recognized as an internal or external command". I'm at a complete loss so sorry if I come off as frustrated.

Comment: Did you install the tool? Looks like the instructions are to clone the repo locally and then run `npm install -g` from inside the repo. After that, I would imagine `sink` is available in your PATH.